# How to set URL rewrite rule for different paths

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, yii, yii-url-manager

I have this statement in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    IndexIgnore */*

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

My files are stored in: `C:\xampp\htdocs\test505,com\`, and I have a virtual host named `test505.com` pointing to that directory, and a defined host in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file, also named `test505.com`.

I even have a `localhost` virtual host defined which points into `C:\xampp\htdocs`, and it works fine.

If I run: `http://test505.com/` and fill the URL after /, it will work OK as expected, but if I do: `localhost/test505.com/`, it will not work properly and URL's won't be overwritten...

How can I make it run properly on both host names, nevermind the path names?

I have no idea how to solve this, so any help is appreciated!

---

**Note:** I use PHP with Yii Framework, with enabled URL paths for URL formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # For sites running on a port other than 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^localhost\/test505\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://test505.com:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1 [L,R]

# And for a site running on port 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^localhost\/test505\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://test505.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Something like this can help. Try to read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Where have I mentioned ports?

Comment: hm.. Whats with you and ports? its standart example. If you got defined virtual host you need to define port there, if it's diff then 80 you need to use 1st variant and if 80 2nd. What the problem?